# Error inserting policy. (CADES - Bouncy Castle c #)

Tags: c#

Error: IdAaEtsSigPolicyId Disapproved. Inconsistency in IdAaEtsSigPolicyIdentifier: the cryptographic summaries of the attribute and the POLICY are not the same.

```
byte[] messageHash = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(entRes);
    
byte[] certHash = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(cert.RawData);
    
DerObjectIdentifier derobjectidentifier = new DerObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1");
signedAttributes.Add(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.Attribute(CmsAttributes.ContentType, new DerSet(derobjectidentifier)));
    
//1.2.840.113549.1.9.4 -> messageDigest
signedAttributes.Add(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.Attribute(CmsAttributes.MessageDigest, new DerSet(new DerOctetString(messageHash))));
    
//1.2.840.113549.1.9.5 -> Signing Time
signedAttributes.Add(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.Attribute(CmsAttributes.SigningTime, new DerSet(new DerUtcTime(DateTime.Now))));
    
AlgorithmIdentifier algorithmIdentifier = new AlgorithmIdentifier(new DerObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1"));
    
byte[] policyHASH = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("E98BC76B0149E632CD639DE76682EE72D97F927C255C28B04A3DBCFEC632285F");
    
//sigPolicyQualifier-spuri
SigPolicyQualifierInfo bcSigPolicyQualifierInfo = new SigPolicyQualifierInfo(new DerObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.5.1"), new DerIA5String("http://politicas.icpbrasil.gov.br/PA_AD_RB_v2_3.der"));
    
//id-aa-ets-sigPolicyId             
SignaturePolicyId signaturePolicyId = new SignaturePolicyId(DerObjectIdentifier.GetInstance(new DerObjectIdentifier("2.16.76.1.7.1.1.2.3")), new OtherHashAlgAndValue(algorithmIdentifier, new DerOctetString(policyHASH)), bcSigPolicyQualifierInfo);
    
//id-aa-ets-sigPolicyId - OID 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.15
DerObjectIdentifier identificadorPolicyID = new DerObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.15");
signedAttributes.Add(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.Attribute(identificadorPolicyID, new DerSet(signaturePolicyId)));
    
    
CmsSignedDataGenWithRsaCsp cms = new CmsSignedDataGenWithRsaCsp();
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParameter = null;
                   
dynamic rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;           
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certCopy = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);            
                    
cms.MyAddSigner(rsa, certCopy, keyParameter, CmsSignedDataGenerator.EncryptionRsa,  CmsSignedDataGenerator.DigestSha256, attributeTable, null);
```

Need help!

Comment: did you able to resolve this ? If you got this working, can you please share the working code ?